# Summand of a subgroup in a torus

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

Let $\mathbb{T}^n := \mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{Z}^n$ denote the $n-$dimensional torus. If $K$ is a closed normal subgroup of $\mathbb{T}^n$, then does there exist a subgroup $L$ of $\mathbb{T}^n$ such that $\mathbb{T}^n$ is an internal direct product of $K$ and $L$?

Comment: Can you do this when n is 2?

Comment: Notice that K will have to be connected.